# Is it possible to have a file exe.settings whose values will adapt to the installation folder of the msi?

Tags: .net, windows-installer, settings

So, I have an application built under vs2010 and the app has sone values defined in the file .exe.config. Some of these values are paths, and the paths may vary because it depends on the installation folder chosen by the user when running the msi.

Is there any way to define a string in the config file that can be replaced by the actual installation folder?

What I need is something in my config file that looks like:

```
    <setting name="path" serializeAs="String">
       <value>[installationFolder]\Germaine\RapportsBrut\</value>
    </setting>
```

This way, I will have a working default location, but the user will be able to change it without breaking the application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use relative paths in your configuration file.

Rather than have an entry like

> C:\MyHardCodedInstallPath\Data\file1.csv

have a relative path in your settings file

> Data\file1.csv

In your code, use Path.Combine to combine that installation path with the relative path.

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(InstallationPath, relativePathFromSettings);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The point of having a config file though, is to allow the user of defining his own values. Your way doesn't allow that as the application will crash with any path that doesn't start with the proper value. As I said, what I want may not exist.

Comment: A settings file should only be edited by a knowledgeable / power user.  An average user can easily mess up an XML file.  If you need an average user to be able to configure paths, you should provide a UI within your application to allow them to do that.  Update the settings file from the app.  Power users should be able to understand relative paths.

Comment: Thanks again, your answers are really appreciated, and right, but it is not what I am looking for. It is an app used by a team of developpers. And the path must not be fully relative because it can be changed to any location. And UI is only appropriate when a value changes everytime. It would be a waste of time... I have a specific need for a specific tool. If I don't get a satisfiing answer, I will stuck with the default path that may not work at the beginning.